# Can I shorten section names of articles for in text citations MLA?

Tags: academic-writing, citations, mla

My professor is requiring I include section names in my MLA in text citation. It’s fine for most of my sources since their section names are one word like “symptoms” and “causes”. But one of them uses whole sentences like “Who is more likely to get Huntington’s disease?” I'm wondering if I need to put the whole section name in parenthesis with the source or if I can shorten it. Shortened would like like (Huntington’s Disease. NINDS Who is…) and long would be (Huntington’s Disease. NINDS Who is more likely to get Huntington’s disease? I tried finding the answer in other places like Purdue but didn’t and the professor is busy over the weekend.

Comment: You're not having a writing problem. Section names aren't part of a citation in MLA, so there is no help that we can give you. Your problem is that your professor demands something of you that deviates from the MLA style, and therefore you need to ask him or her how do do it. If (s)he is unavailable over the weekend, write the citation whichever way you think, then ask your professor next week and correct the citations. In the meantime, write the *text*. There's no reason to dawdle over this question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.